# Download function with overwrite

Tags: java, android

I am doing a function to download files to android device, works fine but I want to do that if the downloaded file exists already in the device will overwrite it. Here is my code:

```
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user 
        // presses the power button during download
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
             getClass().getName());
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mWakeLock.release();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (result != null){

            this.finish();
            }
        else
        {

            Descargar.this.finish();
        }
    }

   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        for (i=0; i< sUrl.length; i++) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[i]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
            // instead of the file
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();

            fOut = openFileOutput(i+".json",MODE_PRIVATE);



            //fOut = new FileOutputStream("/aste/tiempobilbao.json");

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                fOut.write(data, 0, count);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fOut != null)
                    fOut.close();

                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Although I have no clue, I very much doubt you would be able to do this due to the obvious problems with security.  You could overwrite everything.

Comment: To make your code easier to parse, you should include only the relevant parts related to your question. You could put only the `doInBackground()` part.

Comment: ` catch (IOException ignored) {} ` is bad ! Never leave unmanaged exceptions in your code if you want to figure out what's going on. Also, you could give us the code for openFileOutput, and post the content your your logcat which may contains interesting informations.

Comment: Why not use the `DownloadManager` system service? You can query its database to see if a file already exists, and overwrite or reuse it as you see fit. It handles retry/resume automatically in case of network failure. It frees you from having to deal with wakelocks and the like, thereby giving the device owner more control over battery usage and their data bundle.

Answer (score 1):

If the file exist, delete it first.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: What more do you want?

Answer (score 1):

you can delete file before starting download with below code :

> File myFile = new File(fileName);
>
> if(myFile.exists())
>       myFile.delete();

Comment: and where on my code have I to put this code? Thank you very much

Comment: Just before downloading the file (here as myFile).